# Is it possible to do a mass replacement of aging vehicles?

Tags: openttd

I have a bunch of vehicles in need of replacement due to old age. I am aware of the vehicle autoreplacement feature, but that seems to only allow for the migration of one vehicle to another (instead of just decomissioning an older vechicle and replacing it with an exact duplicate.)

Is it possible to auto-replace aged vehicles with identical (newer) equivalents?

Comment: It's been forever since I've played OpenTTD, but I know there's an option to auto-renew vehicles when they enter a depot.  This is a problem if breakdowns/servicing is off, though.

Comment: @thedaian Not really a problem except the game won't stop warning you about old vehicles, when they don't have any effect any more.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go into Advanced Settings, then Vehicles, then Autorenew. Turn on "Autorenew Vehicle when it gets old", then set the other two options in that menu to the values of your choice.

I believe that vehicles will only autorenew when they pass a depot during their normal routes, but I haven't tested this.

[image: Autorenew feature of OpenTTD]

Comment: In the same menu as autoreplacement you can send all vehicles in for maintenance. They will then get replaced, I think.

Comment: Macha You are right WRT to it only working when they enter a depot in normal flow. And as @Zsub mentions, there's an option on the various lists of vehicles to "send for servicing", which will also autorenew any vehicle that needs it when it enters the depot. Just be wary of doing this to *all* your vehicles at once, you'll risk a massive traffic jam - consider using groups to send them in batches, or instead put a "service at depot" order in every vehicles' order plan.

Comment: As a note, when the number is positive the vehicle will be replaced that amount of time after its age limit; if it is negative the it will be replaced before its age limit is reached. So, e.g., if the value is -12 vehicles will be auto-replaced one year before they hit their age limits.

Comment: In the current version (1.5.1), the setting is under 'Company' instead of 'Vehicles'.

Comment: Just to update: In 1.6.1, this option has been moved under the "company" tab.